# How can I solve the issue I have with PsExec?

Tags: vb.net, windows, command, psexec

A method in which I test the internet connection is not working when I execute the program using PsExec.
It shows this message:

> "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden"**

I need to execute the application remotely, that's why I use PsExec, but when I open the program without using PsExec the method runs ok.

The command I use to execute the program with PsExec:

```
"D:\PsExec.exe -s -i \\MK18455 D:\RemedyHealthCheck.exe "
```

The method:

```
Public Shared Function CheckForInternetConnection(link As String) As String
    Try
        Dim proxy As New WebProxy("ibproxy03.intranet.ibermatica:8080", True)
        proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = True

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(link)
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        request.Proxy = proxy


        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

        If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            Return "si"
        Else
            Return "no"
        End If
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox(e.Message)
        Return "no"
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: Define 'Not working'. Is there any error message?

Comment: @AFriend Yes, it shows a message: "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden"

Comment: I see you're using default credentials. If you're trying to access remotely you should need to provide proper credentials

Comment: @AFriend For example?

Comment: @AFriend Because I have tried with the username and password of the computer I'm accessing to

Comment: Do you mean you tried using the `-u` and `-p` option for psexec instead of the `-s` option, or that you tried modifying the code to provide the necessary credentials?  (Note that if you are using `-u` and `-p` it must be **instead** of `-s` not as well as.)

Comment: I've modified the method code, not the command. I'm going to try the other option you said, Thanks.

Comment: It might be a good idea to post the modified code in addition to the original code.  Also, the logs on the proxy might give you useful information, at the very least you could find out whether the error is coming from the proxy or from the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You are running psexec with the wrong user. when you set the -s flag you are actually running as the SYSTEM account, but your web server/proxy requires authentication. you should either allow that computer to bypass the authentication or remove the -s flag, assuming that the user running the psexec is allowed to access that webserver/proxy. another option is to manually set the -u flag to a user that is allowed. (needs a password if you are not running as that user)